# Electron showMessageBox not blocking the process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

From the docs of `dialog.showMessageBox()`:

> ...
>   Shows a message box, it will block the process until the message box is closed.

The problem I'm having is the following, I want to modify a value after the message box is closed. This is my code

```
...
  const win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0];
  const options = {
    buttons: ['Ok'],
    title: ' ',
    message: 'Now listening on ' + adress + ":" + port,
  };
  foo = true;
  const response = dialog.showMessageBox(win, options);
  foo = false;
  console.log("hello");
```

After debugging, I saw that foo is being modified, altough the dialog box is not closed. I also tried to modify it with a callback, as follows:

```
lock = true;
const response = dialog.showMessageBox(win, options, () => {
    lock = false;
);
```

It also didn't work. Could someone explain why it's not working neither of both approaches? And how could I fix it to behave as intended.

Comment: Seems to be an error in the docs... you need `dialog.showMessageBoxSync`

Comment: @ChrisG I see! Thanks. My first approach works now, but the callback one not. You have any clue why?

Comment: [`dialog.showMessageBox`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options) doesn't have a third parameter. It returns a Promise which will resolve to an object containing the user's choice. Use `.then()` or `async` / `await` to read the response.

Comment: @ChrisG Ok, so basically it returns the promise "automatically" and doesn't wait. Percet! If you want to add this as an answer I can mark this as closed.

Comment: do it with 'async - await' concept it will work @Norhther